# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found -- почему Python3 выдаёт ошибку в join и как её исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(100):
    a.append(random.randint(0,1618915))
print(' '.join(a))
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(' '.join(a))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: вы можете просто `print(*a)` вместо `print(' '.join(map(str, a)))` писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что Вы пытаетесь конкатенировать строки и числа, чего в *Python* делать нельзя. Вначале нужно преобразовать числа в строки. Вот несколько вариантов как это можно сделать.

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in a)

' '.join([str(x) for x in a])

' '.join(map(str, a))
```